# Persists the "Awaken"-Spell through Polymorph

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, polymorph

DND 5e Question:
What would happen, if you Polymorph a Zombie or another low Int Creature to a Plant or lower Int Beast like a Wolf, Awaken it and then let the Polymorph run out?(This would need two Casters, one to start the Awaken Cast and one to Polymorph the target before Awaken is actually casted)

Would the target stay an Awakened Plant. Would the Zombie be Awakened after returning to it's previous form? As it would return to it's original Stat-block, it would probably lose it's newfound Intelligence and it's newly gained Language(Speaking, but not sure about understanding)

Comment: Your title is confusing.   Do you mind if I edit it into standard English?